# How to protect the prompt (make it read-only) in Emacs term-mode?

Tags: emacs

With shell-mode, I can do `(setq comint-prompt-read-only t)` to protect the prompt. The cursor is blocked when I try to move the cursor to the left. The prompt also cannot get erased.

Is there a similar feature with `term` and `ansi-term`?

Comment: The default behavior of `term` and `ansi-term` with a recent version of Emacs Trunk is to protect the prompt such that it cannot be erased with the backspace key, and the arrow key does not permit moving the cursor into the area of the prompt.